# Run a Google Script with a Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wish to run the next script, with a script.

When function "ConfigureTest1" has run, it should simply start "ConfigureTest2" and so on...

This is what I have, so far:**

```
function ConfigureTest1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('TEST')
  sh
  .getRange('A2:A')
  .createTextFinder('T')
  .replaceAllWith('TEST')

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('ConfigureTest2') // RUN function ConfigureTest2 
  .create();

}

function ConfigureTest2() {
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AUTO")
let data = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues()
let initialData = data.map(function(r) {
return r[0];
})
let conde = ["TEST"]
let writea = ["TEST"]
let rowNumber = 2
for (i = 0; i <= ss.getLastRow() - 2; i++) {
for (j = 0; j <= conde.length - 1; j++) {
if (initialData[i].includes(conde[j])) {
ss.getRange("B" + rowNumber).setValue(writea[j])
break
}
ss.getRange("B" + rowNumber).setValue("TEST")
}
rowNumber++
}
}
```

Comment: How about `function runAll() { ConfigureTest1(); ConfigureTest2(); }`?

Comment: Not exactly what I needed, but it worked.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add more details about the expected solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just add `ConfigureTest2()` after creating the trigger like this:

```
function ConfigureTest1() {

  //what you already have
  
  ConfigureTest2()
}
```

I'm not sure what's your final purpose with the script, but as some additional advice, the [TriggerBuilder documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder) explains that you first need to specify what kind of trigger this is  along with the ID of the document that you want to attach it to, and then specify the [type of trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder), so your trigger creation should look more like this:

```js
ScriptApp.newTrigger('ConfigureTest2')
  .forSpreadsheet("<Your-spreadsheet-ID>")
  .onOpen() //or edit, etc.
  .create();
```

And also note that the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method applies to an entire array, but you're trying to call it on just one element of it, so instead of this:

```
if (initialData[i].includes(conde[j])) {
```

You need to change it to this:

```
if (initialData.includes(conde[j])) {
```

This does copy some "TEST" data to a different column when you run `ConfigureTest1`, but again, I'm not sure what your goal is. At least this should solve the syntax errors so you can focus on the logic of the script.

Comment: I have many different combinations of flows where scripts need to run in the correct order. To awoid to many manual triggers the solution could be to simply perform the function, then the next, the next and so on, and with this option it would be very easy to make multiple combinations.

Comment: It should be fine to just chain the next function within each one like in my first example then. You can keep doing it within the next function and so on. It will also make sure that the order is respected. If that helps feel free to mark the answer as accepted so other users can benefit from it as well.